# medical school vs faculty of medicine

Tags: word-choice

Can I say "**I study in a faculty of medicine**." instead of "**I study in a medical school?**"

Would it sound natural?

Or should I just say "I am studying medicine at (name of institution)."

Let me put it this way: Can we replace "**medical school**" with "**the faculty of medicine"**, and if so would these sound natural?

▪ I was an A student, on my way to medical school.
▪ They never taught me in medical school that I would be doing so much paperwork.

Thank you for reading. I appreciate it.

Comment: Look up "faculty" in a good dictionary. Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris — It's not quite that simple. The word faculty can be used in a general sense, but in some universities it refers to a hierarchical subdivision. And a definition might not distinguish usage. But the poster should say where in the world he is, because that also determines usage.

Comment: @Kris  When I looked it up I saw this:[countable] a department or group of related departments within a university ⇨ school
faculty of
 the Faculty of Law
 the Engineering Faculty     That's why I asked a question. Thanks for being extra helpful.

Comment: "... a department or group of related departments" clearly enough. A student is not a part of faculty. HTH.

Comment: @David Please see my comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *faculty* in English can be used for an institution of higher education that is smaller than a university and bigger than a department.  A faculty, in this sense, is a part of a university, and normally comprises several departments. There can thus be, at a particular university, the faculty of medicine, the faculty of law, the faculty of engineering, the faculty of the humanities, and so forth. Hearing this use of the word may leave an impression that it is, in the context of education, the equivalent of similarly-sounding words in other languages, such as *Fakultät* in German, and *faculté* in French. If one's primary language is not English, and one is used to referring to such educational institutions by a similar word in one's primary language, one will naturally have a tendency to use the word *faculty* for them when speaking English. That tendency will be reinforced by consulting a dictionary, which will reassure one that this is indeed a correct way to use the word.

There are, however, a couple of subtleties about the use of this word, that may not be obvious from a typical dictionary entry for it. First, in the U.S., the word stands for those who teach at a particular school, considered collectively. While standard dictionaries duly note that the word has this sense in the U.S., they often fail to make it clear that this sense dominates the U.S. usage so completely, that using it in the sense outlined in the first paragraph would not be understood by an average native speaker of American English. Probably the only people in the U.S. who would understand it are those who have had some experience interacting with foreign educational systems.

Second, even though the phrases such as *the faculty of medicine* are readily understood in the English-speaking countries other than the U.S., their register is more formal than of the corresponding phrases in, say, French. Somebody studying medicine at the University of Toronto may write that he is enrolled at the Faculty of Medicine when filling out some bureaucratic form, or on his resume, but is unlikely use such a phrase in casual conversation. If he happens to run into a friend while walking to his classes, he probably won't use the word *faculty* in telling the friend where he is going. His counterpart in France, on the other hand, would, in such a situation, quite naturally say that he is going to his 'fac'. (The fact that this abbreviated version of *faculté* exists is itself revealing of how much the word is a part of everyday French vocabulary; nothing like that can be found in English.) A tendency to overuse the word *faculty* in this sense is thus likely to identify one as a foreigner, even if one's English is fluent and formally impeccable.

Answer (score 1):

What "faculty" means depends on where you are. In British English, it is often used to mean a division of a university. In American English, however, "faculty" means the *teachers* at a school (of any level). If you say "I study at the faculty of medicine" it *will* confuse many people.

"Medical school" is usually used specifically for graduate programs in America, while "the School/College/Faculty of Medicine" is probably the department of your university. 4-year programs are often called "Pre-med" in America, and prepare you to get into medical school (both of which could be part of the School of Medicine). In other countries with different medical education traditions, this may be different.

As such, I'd recommend saying, "**I am studying medicine at (name of institution)**." It is the least ambiguous, and less likely to cause regional misunderstandings.

For the second part of your question...

> Can we replace "medical school" with "the faculty of medicine", and if so would these sound natural?

The short answer is no. As I explained above, "medical school" is usually used in a way that is less specific to the institution, and more specific to the level of education.

Both examples you gave are perfect examples of how to use "medical school" as a general level/category, and could not be replaced with "faculty" or its equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

(1) At some institutions, the medical school is called "the faculty of medicine".  (2) But at other institutions, it is the instructors who teach at the medical school which constitute "the faculty of medicine".

A medical student saying "I am in the faculty of medicine" is quite all right in (1).  But not in (2).

My impression is that (1) is more common in Eastern Europe, but I have no data to back that up.