# Which preposition is correct? “In” or “at” the Faculty?

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following expressions is correct?

1. I'm student in the Faculty of Technical Sciences at the University of Novi Sad?
2. I'm student at the Faculty of Technical Sciences at the University of Novi Sad?

Comment: "Faculty", used in this sense, is odd enough in the US that it's going to sound strange no matter what.  "At" would likely cause a hair less confusion, as it would not not imply that you are a member of "the faculty".

Comment: Related: [medical school vs faculty of medicine](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460564/medical-school-vs-faculty-of-medicine/461077).

Comment: 'In' uses the container metaphor; while this may just be intended to convey 'within the buildings complex', there is a very strong hint of inclusion, being one of the firm/family. 'At' hints at non-inclusiveness. // Both are grammatical. // I'm sure this has been covered before ... perhaps 'in/at the office', but the connotations differ subtly there. // I can't help thinking of 'workin' down't mill'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth so does this mean that 'in' is preferred in your opinion? From my point of view 'a student in the faculty' means student is included within the wider academic faculty (not the teaching faculty) and receiving classes etc. -- and so I would have a preference for in over at